# How do you modify standard HTML elements using web components?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I've read how you can create your own web components which can be assigned custom attributes and markup which is encapsulated inside the Shadow DOM. But how can I modify already registered standard HTML elements?

I noticed that [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) have done this because you can add attributes like flex and layout to standard HTML elements.

```
<div horizontal layout>
    <div>Alpha</div>
    <div flex>Beta (flex)</div>
    <div>Gamma</div>
</div>
```

I've looked but I'm unable to find anything that explains how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of polymer's layout attributes, these are purely css hooks: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/layout.html. I think you're also asking for functionality/decoration. Custom elements don't have this notion, but you can create an element that is away of custom attributes you define.

For example, core-header-panel knows hows to deal with children elements that have the `main` attribute:

```
<core-header-panel>
  ...
  <div main>Main content</div>
</core-header-panel>
```

Comment: Ah ok, so Polymer havent even touched the standard HTML elements. Their just reserving certain attribute names for style hooks. If I wanted to change/add functionality to standard HTML elements are you saying the only way you could do this is to nest them inside a custom element?

Comment: No necessarily. You'd just have to build your app to be knowledgable about those attributes. Custom elements make this easier because they can the logic can live within the component. The reason we use attributes for a lot of things in Polymer (instead of classes) is because we get property observation (e.g. `<prop>Changed`) handlers and styling hooks...all in one :)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm still reading up on web components and Polymer so I'm sure it will make sense after some practice. Thanks.